# IOS Rich notification handle dismiss event

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

We are in the process of sending rich notification to users of our apps but we had to track 'dismiss' event of notification too. Apple is providing only 'received' event for notification.

How can we track dismiss event with API?

Related document:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension